# Minimizing matrix norm via similarity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-transformations

What algorithms or references can I look into in order to find a transformation $T$ that minimizes the norm of a given matrix $A$ with no particular properties?

$$\min_T \| T A T^{-1} \|$$

The norm I want to minimize is the $2$-norm, but the Frobenius norm also works because it bounds (tightly) the $2$-norm. Thus, it should yield similar $T$. Matrix $A$ is real in some applications and imaginary in others. Either solution would help.

Comment: What norm you want to minimize? There are several norms on matrix space — operator norm, l^p vector norms etc. Also, are you considering real or complex case?

Comment: The norm I want to minimize is the 2-norm, but Frobenius norm also works because it bounds (tightly) the 2-norm. The matrix A is real in some applications and imaginary in others. Either solution would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of all invertible matrices is not compact. There is no guarantee that a minimum exists, but you may look at the infimum instead. We shall show that $\inf_T\|TAT^{-1}\|_2=\rho(A)$ and $\inf_T\|TAT^{-1}\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_i|\lambda_i(A)|^2}$.

It is clear that $\|TAT^{-1}\|_2\ge\rho(TAT^{-1})=\rho(A)$. Also, since Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant and every complex matrix is unitarily triangulable, $\|TAT^{-1}\|_F$ is always bounded below by $\sqrt{\sum_i|\lambda_i(A)|^2}$.

Now, suppose $T_1AT_1^{-1}$ is the Jordan normal form of $A$. Let $T_2=\operatorname{diag}(1,k,k^2,\ldots,k^{n-1})$ where $k>0$. When $k\to+\infty$, $T_2(T_1AT_1^{-1})T_2^{-1}\to\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. Therefore, its induced $2$-norm approaches $\rho(A)$ and its Frobenius norm approaches $\sqrt{\sum_i|\lambda_i(A)|^2}$. Hence the two lower bounds are infima.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Then the solution is as simple as taking T to be the transformation to Jordan canonical form.
Could you explain the argument with $T_2$ though?

Comment: @AlexPacheco (1) No, that $T$ is not a solution. In fact, as I said right at the beginning, $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is not compact. There is **no** solution in general. (2) When $J=T_1AT_1^{-1}$ is a Jordan form, just calculate $T_2JT_2^{-1}$ directly.

Comment: I will detail it mathematically in my work, but for engineering purposes: If the goal is to minimize the 2-norm/f-norm then computing the jacobian transform is the closest we can get to a solution assuming a solution exists? At least that's how I interpret what you are saying..

Comment: @AlexPacheco That's not what I'm saying. Consider the case that $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$. This is already a Jordan form. But $\|A\|_2=1$ is far from minimal. In fact, if $T_2(k)=diag(1,k)$, then $T_2(k)AT_2(k)^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&1/k\\ 0&0}$ and hence $\|T_2(k)AT_2(k)^{-1}\|_2=\frac1k$. Therefore, $$\|A\|_2=1>\|T_2(2)AT_2(2)^{-1}\|_2=\frac12>\|T_2(3)AT_2(3)^{-1}\|_2=\frac13>\cdots$$ There is no end to this descending chain and every $T_2(k)AT_2(k)^{-1}$ with $k\ge2$ is a better choice than the Jordan form $A$.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation !