# Minima of a sum of matrix norms $||T^{-1}AT||_F + ||T^{-1}BT||_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, jordan-normal-form

I have learned in a previous question that a lower bound of $||T^{-1}AT||_F$ is $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(A)|^2}$ for some $T$ and $\lambda_i(A)$ are the eigenvalues of $A$

Proof:
Suppose $J=T_1^{-1}AT_1$ is the Jordan form of $A$. Let $T_2$=diag($1,k,k^2,...k^{n-1}$) where $k>0$. As $k\rightarrow \infty$ ,  $T_2^{-1}JT_2 \rightarrow $ diag($\lambda_1,...\lambda_n$) and thus the Frobenius norm approaches $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(A)|^2}$  from above.

Thus I use $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i(A)|^2}$  as the result for

Given $A$

$\min_T ||T^{-1}AT||_F$

How could I go about finding a result for

Given $A$, $B$

$\min_T ||T^{-1}AT||_F + ||T^{-1}BT||_F$

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Link to previous question:
[Minimizing matrix norm via similarity transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710807/minimizing-matrix-norm-via-similarity-transformation)

Comment: No link to other post or definitions made, such as what's $\lambda_i$

Comment: Fixed, thank you!